# swift 3 CoreData strange debugger warning when using UIAlertController with text

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uialertcontroller

Hi I'm building the coreData for swift 3. I'm Using the Master-Detail Template (only ad 1 more detail field for the prototype cell). I created a `alertController` and handle text input then save to coreData. Don't know why there is strange debugger warning.

here is my insert function

```
func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "User", message: "Please enter username", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) in

            if let textField = alert.textFields?.first {
                let newEvent = Event(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event", in: context)!, insertInto: context)
                newEvent.timestamp = Date()

                newEvent.user = textField.text

                // Save the context.
                context.saveContext()
            }


        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter username"
        }

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

When I run. Everything work fine but have this warning. [image]

I'm using prototype cell with `Detail` template. Any using auto cell sizing

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Anyone know what it is and how to avoid this? Thanks

Comment: this crash is regarding your collectiionView, it has nothing to do with UIAlertController

Comment: any particular detail how to dissmiss this warning? i'm using master-detail template

Comment: reduce height of your collectionviewcell?

Comment: Hi I'm using tableview. cell is from TableViewAutomaticDimension (2 function at the bottom)

Comment: the error shows UICollectionView and UIcollectionViewFlowLayout